# Phase velocity of optical branch of lattice vibration at zone center

Tags: solid-state-physics, dispersion

In a 1-D diatomic lattice, the dispersion relation for lattice vibration is given by:

$\omega =\surd( \beta (1/M + 1/m)+\beta(\surd(1/M + 1/m)^2 -4sin^2ka/Mm))$

$v = \omega/k$
gives the phase velocity.
 At $ka = 0$(zone center), the phase velocity comes out to be infinity.
is this correct?
the group velocity is zero as there is a local maxima in the zone center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a standing wave ($v_{\rm group}=0$) of infinite wavelength with a finite frequency. So yes, the phase velocity is also infinite.